# Updated some VM's from 12 LTS to 14.04.1 LTS, and now network throughput is bad, any ideas?

Tags: networking

I decided to bite the bullet after seeing the messages about going to 14, and ran the upgrade scripts. This all seemed to go well, so I kept going and updated all 3 of my VM's that are running Ubuntu server.

At this time, my servers all say they are 14.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-36-generic x86_64), and I thought were doing fine.   I just realized that for whatever reason, my outbound network throughput from any of the VM's is horrible.  If I am transferring a file to the servers it seems to work well, but as soon as I try and transfer a file off the server, I am lucky if I can get a couple meg on a GigE link.  I went and tried this on all three of my upgraded ubuntu VM's and all are acting the same.  I know they were fine under 12, as a couple of the machines ran pretty heavy bandwidth at times.

To see if it was just the upgraded ubuntu machines, I also have some VM's that are running FreeBSD, and some running CentOS, and doing file transfers on the other OS's are still working just fine, with great throughput.

So I am not sure what changed, but something happened with the updates to 14.04.01 that has really hammered it's networking.   I can't find anything sticking out that is wrong, so if anyone has any ideas how I can sort this out and get my VM's running well again it would sure be a big help..

Thanks, Howard..

Comment: I went back and installed the 3.8.13 kernel from Ubuntu, in place of the one that comes with 14, and now my network is working OK.   So I guess the million dollar question now, is what changed in the new kernel that is making it run horrible as a VM.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to go back to 12.04? If so, do that! You probably have made snapshots. Make sure everything is working like before.

Then create a test VM from one of the 12.04 snapshots. Update it to 14, see how that performs and proceed from there. This gives you time, as there is no need to update to 14 right now.

When upgrading the live systems, only update one VM. Test it, leave it for a week, then do VM 2, etc.

Comment: That would be great, other than I took the opportunity to update one, thought I didn't have a backup, and it seemed to be running fine, so I did the rest.   I guess unless someone has an idea as to how to debug this issue, I am going to be reloading 3x machines.  Live and learn I guess..

Comment: If you can go back without losing data, yes, do it now. Then test it out. You lost some time, but it will give you the opportunity to find the cause without feeling rushed. Another opportunity is to find a good linux network admin, and pay for a solution.